# One SSL Certificate for two servers?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, website

we have set up one productive server and a testing environment, which are two VMs with different internal IP addresses.
Our public DNS server points software.example.com to our public IP address.
If you want to use the productive server you would type in https://software.example.com and if you want to access the server for testing you would use https://software.example.com:10443.
Our firewall would then redirect the request to the right internal IP.

This is sufficient for external use, as we can use the same SSL certificate for two servers (as they use the same FQDN).
But we need to use the internal IP for the productive server, because it should be available even when the internet connection is down.
So I used an A record to the internal IP of the productive server.

Now we can not open the testing website using the DNS name, because software.example.com points to the productive server internally, we just can use the internal IP like 192.168.1.10:10443, which results in a SSL certificate error.

Do you know a way around this?
I would like to find a way to make the address software.example.com work internally for both servers. I wouldn't like to make the website accessible through the internet connection only.

I could use a different certificate for the testing environment, but I would have to go with let's encrypt, a way to use our paid certificate from our provider would be better.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1. Install a load balancer / reverse proxy internally in front of the two servers, and point the domain `software.example.com` to the IP of the reverse proxy, that way you can use the same setup as you're using externally. This can be done using for example NGINX, MS IIS or an F5.
2. You can also use the web server running the production environment to forward requests internally to the testing environment. This of course requires that the web server on the production server supports a reverse proxy configuration. This has the added benefit of saving you an extra server.
3. Set up a different domain, say `software-testing.example.com`, for the testing environment and install a different certificate on that server. This is in my opinion the cleanest option, since you're not sharing any infrastructure, and an SSL certificate is rather cheap compared to running extra servers and maintaining them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer the question in the title, you would use the [SAN](https://www.ssl.com/faqs/what-is-a-san-certificate/) (Subject Alternate Name) field when creating your CSR or ordering your certficate.  SAN allows a single certificate to be valid for two (or more) host names.

Looking at the body of the question, though, you seem more interested in having a single name which will always reach your internal server, even when external networking is unavailable, rather than a single certificate which is valid for multiple names.  There are several ways this can be done.  Here are the first few to mind:

1. Set up an internal DNS server which is private to your network and returns the internal IP address for internal machines (e.g., 192.168.1.10 for software.example.com) and forwards the request to an external DNS server (e.g., your ISP or 8.8.8.8) for non-internal names.  This is the "most correct" solution and the easiest if you already have an internal DNS server, but, if you don't already have one, you'll have to set one up and reconfigure all your internal machines to use it.
2. Configure a "hosts file" (`/etc/hosts` on Linux, check google for locations on Windows, OS X, or other operating systems) on all your internal machines to tell them that software.example.com is at 192.168.1.10 without going through DNS.  This has the same general effect as #1, but it's a lot more work to set up and maintain.  Its only advantage is that it avoids having to set up an internal DNS server.
3. Tell your internal users to use the IP address or an alternate name for internal access at all times, regardless of whether your internet is up or down.  If you don't have the corresponding SAN on your certificate, they can "accept the risk and continue" when their browser complains about the certificate being invalid.  If you don't have the SAN, this is a very "not-correct" solution (because it involves ignoring browser security warnings), but it's the easiest to implement if you don't have the networking infrastructure already in place for any of the other solutions.
4. If you have a configurable router handling your internal network's traffic, you can set it to send traffic for your server's external IP address directly to the server without routing it out the internet connection and back.  This keeps the internally-visible IP address the same regardless of whether the connection is up or down, but it's the most esoteric solution, so it should be well-documented if you do this to avoid confusing someone (quite likely yourself) who has to debug a routing problem sometime in the future.  It also might not help anyhow if you aren't able to access external DNS servers when your connection goes down - which brings us back to "set up an internal DNS and use solution #1."

Comment: Thanks you for your resonse.
I like method number 4, I'm going to try this out.